# Passport.js: Serialization issue with local login strategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm having trouble authenticating a small passport.js example project when I switch over to mongodb instead of a local array.

MongoDB is able to connect and add users from a form on the home page. On login however, there are problems.

Not sure if this matters but on the /login page onload I see 2 red errors in the browser console:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
login:1 
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

I put a log statement in the relevant route handler. It does not reach or log to the console.

```
app.post('/login', function sendUserRecordToAxiosOrRedirect(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function controlErrorsOrSuccess(error, userRecord, info) {
    console.log('inside pp.auth callback');
    if (error) return next(error);
    if (userRecord == false) return res.json ({ "error" : "Invalid Username" });
    if (userRecord) {
      console.log('---- User Found: INFO --------');
      console.log(info);
      res.redirect('/')
    }
  })
});
```

From the above I suspected something is awry with the Strategy I give to passport. The log statement in this one doesn't fire either:

```
passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    console.log('inside Strategy');
    db.users.findInDatabaseByUsername(username, function (error, userRecord) {
      if (error) return done(error);
      if (userRecord == false) return done(null, false); // no error, no userRecord
      if (userRecord.password !== password) return done(null, false); 
      return done(null, userRecord); 
    })
  }
));
```

Since  I altered my serialization functions to search the database instead of an array I suspect the problem may lie here. Neither of the log statements here fire either:

```
const passUserIdOnlyToACallback = function(userRecord, callbackFunction) {
  console.log("serializing...");
  callbackFunction(null, userRecord.id);
};
passport.serializeUser(passUserIdOnlyToACallback); 

function passUserRecordToCallbackById(userId, verifyCallback) {
  db.users.findInDatabaseById(userId, function(error, userRecord) {
    console.log("deserializing...");
    if (error) return verifyCallback(error);
    verifyCallback(null, userRecord) 
  })
}
passport.deserializeUser(passUserRecordToCallbackById);
```

Everything was working fine initially with the local array code, so my alterations broke something. Does anyone see the error?